# How to deny moving node to root in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

a have a tree like a:

```
[{
    "data": "reference",
    "attr":{"id":"1"},
    "children": [{
        "data": "reference child",
        "attr":{"id":"3"}
     }]
}, 
{
    "data": "recycle bin",
    "attr":{"id":"2"}
}]
```

I need deny moving "reference child" to root by using "check_move".

Comment: can u show some example from -> to?

Comment: "check_move": function(m){ return (
m.o[0].id !== "1" &&
m.o[0].id !== "2"
);}

Comment: this is works for dragging reference & recycle bin (they have id 1 & 2)